# Composer, how to upgrade dev dependencies only

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there a way to only upgrade `require-dev` packages and not `require` ones in composer?

In composer.json I changed several `require-dev` packages but I don't want the other non-dev packages and their dependencies to change their locked version.

I can't find anything in the docs. The only solution I can think of is to change the version in composer.json and launch a `composer update <list of all updated packages>`, but it's a bit tedious if you have many dependencies to upgrade as in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Composer doesn't offer this option directly, but you can compose other commands to get the list of direct development dependencies.

You could try this:

```
composer update $(composer show --name-only -D | grep -E -v "$(composer show --no-dev --name-only -D | paste -sd '|' -)")
```

`composer show --name-only -D` - lists the names of all direct dependencies

`composer show --no-dev --name-only -D | paste -sd '|' -)` - gets the names of all direct dependencies excluding development and transforms the output into the string to be executed by the `composer update` method.