# How to update only dev dependencies in Renovate for Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, renovate

How to configure Renovate tool to update only development dependencies for the Composer package manager?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer, how to upgrade dev dependencies only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73704099/composer-how-to-upgrade-dev-dependencies-only)

Comment: @NicoHaase, no. This is a completely different question. I have no idea how someone downvoted the question, because Renovate has nothing to do with manual dependency updates. I created the answer because I stumbled upon this problem today, and didn't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure Renovate to ignore (disable) all the regular dependencies using the directive `matchDepTypes`. Example below:

```json
 "packageRules": [
    {
        "groupName": "regular-dependencies",
        "matchManagers": ["composer"],
        "matchDepTypes": ["require"],
        "enabled": false
    },
```

If you want to update only regular dependencies you need to change the `"matchDepTypes"` to `["require-dev"]`.